# Ember.js: conditional input attribute

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

In Ember's input helper, how can I show/hide attributes based on a condition?  For example, let's say I want to show `required="required"` if `isEditable` is true and `disabled="disabled"` otherwise.  Currently I have something like this:

```
{{#if isEditable}}
    {{input value=model.name required="required"}}
{{else}}
    {{input value=model.name disabled="disabled"}}
{{/if}}
```

...but it would be nice if I bind the attributes somehow instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ input type='text' required=required disabled=disabled }}` works just fine

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kupoti/1/edit?html,js,output)

There are a whole bunch of attributes that you can bind directly and `required` and `disabled` are among the pack. See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/#toc_text-fields)

**Note** @blackmind is correct that if you were to do this from scratch, you would need to do some work. Fortunately though, `TextSupport` already does the work for you... :) See [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.10.0/packages/ember-views/lib/mixins/text_support.js#L112)

Answer (score 2):

From the EmberJS site

By default, view helpers do not accept data attributes. For example

```
{{#link-to "photos" data-toggle="dropdown"}}Photos{{/link-to}}

{{input type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Name"}}
```

renders the following HTML:

```
<a id="ember239" class="ember-view" href="#/photos">Photos</a>

<input id="ember257" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text" title="Name">
```

There are two ways to enable support for data attributes. One way would be to add an attribute binding on the view, e.g. Ember.LinkView or Ember.TextField for the specific attribute:

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-toggle']
});

Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-toggle', 'data-placement']
});
```

Now the same handlebars code above renders the following HTML:

```
<a id="ember240" class="ember-view" href="#/photos" data-toggle="dropdown">Photos</a>

<input id="ember259" class="ember-view ember-text-field" 
       type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Name">
```

Or you can reopen the view

```
Ember.View.reopen({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    var self = this;

    // bind attributes beginning with 'data-'
    Em.keys(this).forEach(function(key) {
      if (key.substr(0, 5) === 'data-') {
        self.get('attributeBindings').pushObject(key);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I typically do the following

```
<input type="checkbox" {{bind-attr disabled=isAdministrator}}>
```